# Slide out menu using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am developing the slide out menu in my project using SWRevealViewController and also did a sample project of slide out menu using SWRevealViewController. the sample project code is working. i wrote same code in my project. But, it is not working. I written the code like this...

```
func slideOutMenus() {
  if revealViewController() != nil {
      hamburgMenuBtn.target = revealViewController()
  hamburgMenuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
  revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 250
  view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
  }
 }
```

when i'm clicking the button,there is no action in that.i'm debugging the code. the revealViewController() shows nil.
How Can i solve this issue? Please help me out.. Advance Thanks
[This is the image of my project...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhKg6.png)

Comment: when slideoutmenus function will be called ?. Is hamburgMenuBtn is button how it is set to navigation bar

Comment: Yes @Vinodh it's already called in viewDidLoad(). yes, hamburgMenuBtn is a button. i'm taking an item button in navigation bar and set image for that and taking Outlet for that.

Comment: post the code . Because am using the same it works fine for me

Comment: You want entire code?

Comment: - (SWRevealViewController*)revealViewController
{
    UIViewController *parent = self;
    Class revealClass = [SWRevealViewController class];
    while ( nil != (parent = [parent parentViewController]) && ![parent isKindOfClass:revealClass] ) {}
    return (id)parent;
} .

Comment: when i'm debugging the code. the parent returns nil.